# Text Following Path Animation Not Exporting

Tags: animation, .fbx, text-object, path

I'm currently working in Blender for my thesis to create animations to export as an FBX to be used in the VR program Simlab VR.

I created an animation where text follows a path, but in two ways.

**First attempt** (file > BuzzingQuestions):

- Created BezierCurve
- Created text
- Put text on curve
- Keyframed X Offset (NOTE: that when I tried to press "I" to keyframe location, rotation, scale, it would show that the beginning and end are *the same*, so one long orange line, resulting in me just keyframing the X Offset)
  = Animation works!
- Export as FBX
- Import into Blender to see
  = Animation not working! [image: Importing FBX to Blender -- keyframes say they are the same??]

**Second attempt** (file > BuzzingQuestions_2):

- Created BezierCurve
- Created text
- Used the Curve modifier so that the text follows the curve
- Created keyframes using transformation (pressing "I" to capture location, rotation, scale)
  = Animation works!
- Go to export as FBX
- Import that FBX file into Blender to see if animation worked
  = shows text NOT following the path but moving from where I established the beginning and ending[image: So many keyframes of moving on X axis??][image: left to right]

Let me know and thanks in advance!

Comment: Outside of mesh deformations from bones and shape-keys, most formats can't export any other mesh animation. You need some specific formats, such as alembic, or use tricks to turn your animation into shape-keys, but these special formats aren't always supported by game engines (because it's mostly meant for movies VFX) or are too heavy for that medium. Depending what you want to do, there are probably other ways to do the animation using bones or shape-keys in a limited and more manageable way for a game engine.

Comment: I have exported animation before as FBX and its worked (I was able to import into Blender and it showed + viewed in VR and it had the animation). So I know that it isn't the Simlab program but this specific animation itself that isn't exporting properly.

Comment: "I have exported animation before" - sure, the thing is as @L0Lock already said, not all export formats can handle all kinds of animations. There are many kinds of different animations, not only how the animation is done (by keyframes for example), but also different kinds of data which is animated, objects, meshes, modifiers, materials etc. - and not all of these data animations are supported by the export format. For example, when you animate the _Offset_ on a text object although a text object is not supported by FBX, then of course the animation is lost as well. Same with _Curve_ modifier.